# Run command after container is created/recreated in docker swarm mode

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm, portainer

I am using portainer to run my docker images that I build on a github action.
I've setup the docker in swarm mode, so when a new images is build the container would be recreated automatically.
Everything works just fine so far, my only problem is, how do I run the database migrations?
I want to run the database migrations command after the new container was created and I cannot figure it out how I could do this.
I know I could create a script an use it as entrypoint, but I read that it's not ok to run the migration command that way.

I am not using docker-compose file, and I would like to avoid using it, it's easier for me to run the containers like this

There is any solution I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

May be RUN will help you?

"The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

Layering RUN instructions and generating commits conforms to the core concepts of Docker where commits are cheap and containers can be created from any point in an image’s history, much like source control."

Comment: From my readings I understand that it's not a good idea to run migrations when building the image. That's why I am searching for an alternative way of running the migrations, after the container has started. A hook or something like this to run a script. I'll keep searching for somethinig

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you are using Github Actions also for deployment or only to build images.

If you have CI/CD system you can consider a scheme, which will trigger DB migration before the deployment. Make sure that migration will not break backward compatibility, so your previous version still able to work with a new schema. Once migration step completed you can deploy your new version in the next step.

If you don't have CI/CD and deploying new version of images manually you can have some ARG/ENV and custom entrypoint in your image. If you enabled it your image will do migration when run. You should treat migration as additional workload, not restart the whole application when performing it (as said above it shouldn't break backward compatibility).